# pycrypto install weird character errors on suse 11.2 with python 2.6 that I thought I would share

Tags: python

A friend was trying to install pycrypto, but we are getting this error that makes absolute no sense.

```
dell102:/tmp/python/pycrypto-2.6.1 # python setup.py install 
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -march=i586 -mtune=i686 -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -     D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fwrapv - fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/MD2.c -o  build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
src/MD2.c:131: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
In file included from src/MD2.c:147:
src/hash_template.c:48: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before â€˜PyObject_HEADâ€™
src/hash_template.c:59: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜PyTypeObjectâ€™
src/hash_template.c: In function â€˜newALGobjectâ€™:
src/hash_template.c:69: warning: implicit declaration of function â€˜PyObject_Newâ€™
src/hash_template.c:69: error: expected expression before â€˜ALGobjectâ€™
src/hash_template.c:69: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
src/hash_template.c: At top level:
src/hash_template.c:76: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:91: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:110: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:122: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:162: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:188: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
src/hash_template.c:190: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â 
src/hash_template.c:304: error: array type has incomplete element type
... and a whole bunch more ...
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The cause for this is python-devel was not installed. 
Just thought I would share.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for this is python-devel was not installed.